# AWS s3 Intelligent tiring management VS management with sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a little misunderstanding about the following configuration pricing.

The problem:
Need to understand best cost effective way to manage object on a bucket (standard type and infrequent access).
I have 2 ways, either create life-cycle on the bucket as in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html.

or do it myself with java SDK ( scan all bucket -> check last modified if bigger than 30 days change to I.T class , etc).
Another solution is to do with by moving the object to intelligent tiering type and let AWS to mange the type of the object, but here there are some constrains as well on the pricing, where the intelligent tearing process should understand if to move the object type or not, scan for new types, etc.

Lets say I have 1M objects in US-bucket and I'm creating lifecycle rule where files which are bigger than 30 days old -> moved them to I.A.

What will my price in the end ?

---

according the [image]

### Question:

### Case Managed by AWS:

Does I'll pay for : a.scanning all data in the bucket every X. days + b.Transition Request + c.object Tags (if i have) + d.Storage itself ????

or only

### Case I'm managing myself:

Run cron Every 30 days - pay for: a.EC2 machine time  + b.List requests on all buckets data + c.Objects Tags + d.lifecycle Transitions (standard -> I.A and reversed) + e.storage

regards,